# Limit matched filter term

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkick

Let's say I have 10 featured products and the rest are non featured products

I want to limit featured product per page to only show 4

So the result will be like

```
Page 1: 12 product - 4 featured and 8 non featured
Page 2: 12 product - 4 featured and 8 non featured
Page 3: 12 product - 2 featured and 8 non featured
```

Is there anyway to do this with elasticsearch ?

Here my current query

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": {
            "match_all": {} 
        },
        "should": [
            { "term": { "featured": { "value": true, "boost": 2 } } }
            // I want to only show 4 featured products per page
        ]
    }
},
"size":12,
"from":0
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this can be done directly with one ES query. I would suggest splitting the query into  two: "only featured" and "all but featured" and handle pagination separately. This can be done with two parallel searches on the client, or with a [mutli search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) in one API call, but still you will have to handle pagination in a custom way.

Comment: I'd make this an answer.